# What permissions does the health_check_user for pgpool-II need?

Tags: postgresql, high-availability, database-management, pgpool

I'm confused about a point of [pg_pool-II's documentation](http://pgpool.projects.postgresql.org/pgpool-II/doc/pgpool-en.html). The `health_check_user` is used to determine the health of DB cluster servers, but what abilities does the `health_check_user` need? As there are no configuration options to get a password for this user, I'm assuming that pg-pool's `health_check_user` will likewise need trust level access to each DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it just needs permission to connect to the databases (same username for all databases).

You don't need to rely on trust auth either, I'm sure you can use a .pgpass file.
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/libpq-pgpass.html

Answer (score 1):

As Richard said, it only needs to connect to the database.

And also you can set password for this user with [health_check_password](http://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/pgpool-en.html#health_check_password)